# The action of periodic map on  the complex of curves

Tags: mapping-class-groups, gt.geometric-topology

Hi, everyone.

Assume $S$ is a genus at least 2 orientable closed surface. And there is a simplical complex 
defined on $S$ called Curve complex.

It is well known that any automorphism of surface $S$ acts on curve complex $\mathcal {C}(S)$ isometrically.

Now I want to know that

For any periodic and irreducible automorphism $f: S\rightarrow S$,  is there a connected subcomplex $W\subset \mathcal {C}(S)$ with infinite diameter such that $f(W)=W$?

Staylor constructed such a $W$. Now there is a handlebody $H$ such that $\partial H=S$.
Let $f$ be as above, $W$ be the disk complex of $H$.

Now I wonder:

Is it still possible that $f(W)=W$?

Comment: What kind of subcomplex?  The orbit of a vertex under f is such a thing.

Comment: @R.Kent  I have edited it again.

Comment: Now I don't see why you can't just take W to be the whole curve complex...

Comment: In my deleted answer my eyes somehow leapt right over "periodic" and landed on "irreducible". 

Comment: What is the subcomplex $W$ for?  What properties do you want it to have?

Comment: @HW:  I don't want the $W$ is equal to the curve complex.


Answer (score 3):

No, this is false. The point is that if you take an irreducible periodic automorphism $f$,
there is no disjointly embedded collection of curves of $\mathcal{C}(S)$ which
is left invariant by $f$ up to isotopy.

Now suppose that the action of $f$ on $\mathcal{C}(S)$ has a fixed point. 
Then this fixed point lies in a unique minimal simplex of $\mathcal{C}(S)$ which
is preserved by $f$ (one may describe this as the intersection over all 
simplices containing the fixed point, since the action is simplicial). But then the vertices of this simplex are permuted by 
$f$, and therefore $f$ is not irreducible, a contradiction.

Comment: @Agol  Since I required that $f$ is not reducible,  $f$ can not fix 
any vertex on $\mathcal {C}(S)$. 

Comment: @Yanqing: usually when you say "f fixes a subspace", you mean that it fixes each point of the subspace pointwise. I took this interpretation of your question (where I figured you meant a subspace, not a subcomplex, since vertices can't be fixed), so in particular, that there is some fixed point. So I think you need to consider carefully what you mean by "fixed subcomplex". 

Comment: @Agol: I have edited it again.

Answer (score 3):

HW seems to have the best response. If, however, you are looking for a proper subcomplex try the following:

First choose a hyperbolic metric on $S$ so that $f$ can be realized as an isometry. Then pick your favorite curve on $S$ and consider the set of curves in the curve complex with length less than or equal to your curve. Call this set $X$. Since $X$ has finite diameter, some neighborhood $N(X)$ will be connected. $N(X)$ is invariant under $f$ by construction. Now there are various ways to enlarge $N(X)$ to have infinite diameter, preserving invariance. For example, take $W$ to be $N(X) \cup \cup_i f^i \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is an infinite geodesic ray beginning at a point of $N(X)$.